# Two columns, and when one is hidden, the other expands the full width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is there a way with pure css to make 2 divs take up 50% width, and then setting a css property such as `display:none` on **one** of the divs, causes the other to take up 100% width?

I'm looking for a solution where I need to only change css on one of the elements for the other to take up the rest of the space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking for is the `flex-grow` property, which tells elements in a flex container to occupy available space.

So when there are two elements on one line, they will take as much space as they can, ultimately compromising 50/50. But if one element is removed, the other will automatically consume the remaining space.

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
}

.box {
    flex-grow: 1;  /* key rule */
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

.box1 {
    /* display: none; */
    background-color: aqua;
}

.box2 {
    /* display: none; */
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box box1"></div>
    <div class="box box2"></div>
</div>
```

### [**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/qwjrm7tb/1/)

Applying `flex-grow: 1` (or `flex: 1`) to a flex container's children ("flex items") tells them to distribute available space evenly among themselves.

With `flex-grow: 1`:

- Four flex items consume 25% each
- Three items = 33.33%
- Two items = 50%
- One item = 100%

Anytime an item is removed, the others will distribute the available space among themselves.

Also read about the [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) property, as the spec makes the following recommendation:

> Authors are encouraged to control flexibility using the `flex` shorthand rather than with `flex-grow` directly, as the shorthand resets any unspecified components to accommodate common uses.
>
> <sub>*source: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#propdef-flex-grow*</sub>

---

*References:*

- [`flex-grow` property definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) ~ MDN
- [`flex-grow` property definition](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-grow/) ~ CSS-Tricks
- [7.1. The `flex-grow` Shorthand](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#propdef-flex-grow) ~ W3C

---

*Browser support:*

Flexbox is supported by all major browsers, [except IE 8 & 9](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). Some recent browser versions, such as Safari 8 and IE10, require [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix). For a quick way to generate prefixes use [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/). More details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276).