# Fully justified horizontal menu with image and separators

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like to achieve this fully justified horizontal menu:
[image]

Justifying is done with flexbox and works, but I could not get the separating mid-dots justified, too; they are made by using css-content via pseudo-class. Also, I am wondering if there's a better way to vertically center the items than faking it by adding a padding as I have done it.

Here's my code and the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fx5u415j/):

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
li.home {
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
nav {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  height: 40px;
}
li::after {
  //padding: 0em 0.4em;
  content: '\00b7';
  pointer-events: none;
}
li.home::after,
li.last::after {
  content: none;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<nav id="main-menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="home">
      <a href="/de"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/40x40/000/fff"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="second"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">One more Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another Item</a></li>
    <li class="last"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 5):

```css
body { margin: 0; }                              /* 1 */

nav {
  height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}

ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;              /* 2 */
    align-items: center;                         /* 2 */
    height: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

li:not(.home) {
    flex: 1;                                      /* 3 */
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px dashed red;                       /* 4 */
    background-color: lightgreen;                 /* 4 */
}

li:not(.home) > a {                               /* 5 */
    display: flex;                    
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
}

li img { vertical-align: bottom; }                /* 6 */

li { position: relative; }                        /* 7 */

li:not(.home):not(:last-child)::before {          /* 8 */
    position: absolute;
    content: '\26AB';                             /* 4 */
    left: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    z-index: 1;
    pointer-events: none;        
}
```

```html
<nav id="main-menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="home">
      <a href="/de"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/40x40/000/fff"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="second"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">One more Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another Item</a></li>
    <li class="last"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fx5u415j/2/)

Notes:

1. [Remove default margins on `body` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/sample.html)
2. [Methods for Aligning Flex Items](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)
3. [Consume all remaining space with `flex-grow` property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37039262/3597276)
4. Borders, background colors, and larger bullets for illustration purposes only
5. Enable anchor elements to fully cover list item space and align text with flex properties
6. [Remove baseline alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31445364/3597276) (i.e., whitespace underneath image)
7. [Establish nearest positioned ancestor for absolute positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning)
8. [Use absolute positioning to align bullets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36817384/3597276)

Answer (score 1):

You can vertically center the items with `align-self: center;` but the dot separators are in my opinion impossible to achieve with pseudo elements like `:before` or `:after`.

I would recommend to use separate `<li>` tags for separators like below:

Note that your image element needs `display: block;` to have a proper height.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
img {
    display: block;
}
li.home {
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  align-self: center;
}
nav {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="main-menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="home">
      <a href="/de"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/40x40/000/fff"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="second"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li class="separator">·</li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li class="separator">·</li>
    <li><a href="#">One more Item</a></li>
    <li class="separator">·</li>
    <li><a href="#">Another Item</a></li>
    <li class="separator">·</li>
    <li class="last"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

[Fiddle version](http://jsfiddle.net/fx5u415j/1/)

Comment: … putting the separator in a <li> tag: isn't this bad practice in terms of semantics?